# Making a target out-of-date if compiler options differ respect to the previously used ones

Tags: linux, bash, shell, makefile, gnu-make

Consider the following directory tree for a made-up toy example that illustrates the problem to solve:

```
- Makefile
- lib.c
+ foo/
   |-- config.mk
+ bar/
   |-- config.mk
```

- Content of `foo/config.mk`:

  ```
  CFLAGS += -DFOO
  ```
- Content of `bar/config.mk`:

  ```
  CFLAGS += -DBAR
  ```
- Calling `make` with `Makefile` for the targets `foo` and `bar` results in the files `foo/config.mk` and `bar/config.mk` being included (by means of the [`include` directive](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Include.html)), respectively, and `lib.o` being built, i.e.:

  ```
  # build lib.o with the macro FOO defined
  $ make foo

  # build lib.o with the macro BAR defined
  $ make bar

  # build lib.o with both the macros FOO and BAR defined
  $ make foo bar
  $ make bar foo
  ```

The default rule for building `lib.o` uses the variable `COMPILE.c`, which is defined (according to the output obtained by calling `make` with the option [`--print-data-base`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Options-Summary.html)) as:

```
COMPILE.c = $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) $(TARGET_ARCH) -c
```

The expansion of `COMPILE.c` depends, among other things, on the value of the variable **`CFLAGS`**, which, in turn, depends on whether `foo/config.mk` or `bar/config.mk` were included, since these makefiles modify the `CFLAGS` variable.

---

What I would like to achieve is to treat the target `lib.o` as an *out-of-date* target if the expansion of the variable `COMPILE.c` that is currently used is not the same as the one used for the previous build of `lib.o`. For example:

```
$ make foo

# It shouldn't rebuild anything since lib.o should be up-to-date
$ make foo

# It should rebuild lib.o since it should be out-of-date
$ make bar

# It should rebuild lib.o since it is again out-of-date
$ make foo bar

# It shouldn't rebuild lib.o since it is up-to-date
$ make bar foo
```

[This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53704068/8012646) explains how I've implemented this behaviour so far. Any suggestion is welcomed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would dump the variable's value in another included makefile and check whether the current value is different from the one from the included makefile. Something like:

```
ifeq ($(filter foo,$(MAKECMDGOALS)),foo)
include foo/config.mk
endif
ifeq ($(filter bar,$(MAKECMDGOALS)),bar)
include bar/config.mk
endif
-include old_compile.mk

COMPILE.c = $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) $(TARGET_ARCH) -c

ifneq ($(COMPILE.c),$(OLD_COMPILE.c))
FORCE := force
endif

lib.o: lib.c $(FORCE)
    $(COMPILE.c) $< -o $@
    echo 'OLD_COMPILE.c := $(COMPILE.c)' > old_compile.mk

.PHONY: foo bar all force

foo bar all: lib.o
```

Demo:

```
$ make foo
cc -DFOO   -c lib.c -o lib.o
echo 'OLD_COMPILE.c := cc -DFOO   -c' > old_compile.mk
$ make foo
make: Nothing to be done for 'foo'.
$ make foo bar
cc -DFOO -DBAR   -c lib.c -o lib.o
echo 'OLD_COMPILE.c := cc -DFOO -DBAR   -c' > old_compile.mk
make: Nothing to be done for 'bar'.
$ make bar foo
make: Nothing to be done for 'bar'.
make: Nothing to be done for 'foo'.
```

Comment: Thank you. I've just finished to study your very nice solution. I would also make `old_compile.mk` both a *phony target* and an *order-only* prerequisite of `lib.o` (i.e., the rule would be `lib.o: lib.c $(FORCE) | old_compile.mk`), so that it is always generated when the target `lib.o` is matched without necessarily triggering the excecution of its recipe. There would be a dedicated rule for generating the target `old_compile.mk`. What do you think about this modification???

Comment: Well, I am not sure I fully understand the effect of having an included makefile with a rule that explicitly builds it, declared as a phony target and also as an order-only prerequisite of another target. Sorry, this is a bit too much for my understanding of the behaviour of make. So I wouldn't do that. Why would you? Moreover, I suspect that my solution would not work any more: if an included makefile has a rule to build it, make builds it and restarts from scratch; this included makefile would thus always give you the up-to-date flags, not the ones that were used for the last compilation.

Comment: Moreover, having `old_compile.mk` generated by the same rule as `lib.o`, and after `lib.o`, has an interesting property: if the compilation fails,  `old_compile.mk` is not generated and the previous state is preserved. While if it is a prerequisite generated by another rule, it will be renewed even if the compilation that follows fails...

Answer (score 1):

Here's my crude mockup that encodes compiler/linker flags directly in filenames. It's just an idea, an actual implementaation should be a bit more robust.

```
empty:=
space:= $(empty) $(empty)
comma:= ,

LDFLAGS_NS=$(subst $(space),$(comma),$(LDFLAGS))
CFLAGS_NS=$(subst $(space),$(comma),$(CFLAGS))

EXEDIR=./test-exedir-cflags=$(CFLAGS_NS)-ldflags=$(LDFLAGS_NS)
EXEDIR_PAT=./test-exedir-*
OBJDIR=./test-objdir-cflags=$(CFLAGS_NS)
OBJDIR_PAT=./test-objdir-*

test.exe: $(EXEDIR)/test.exe
    rm -f test
    ln -s $< $@

$(EXEDIR)/test.exe: test.o
    rm -rf $(EXEDIR_PAT)
    mkdir $(EXEDIR)
    cc $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $<

test.o: $(OBJDIR)/test.o
    rm -f test.o
    ln -s $< $@

$(OBJDIR)/test.o: test.c
    rm -rf $(OBJDIR_PAT)
    mkdir $(OBJDIR)
    cc -c $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $<
```

Tested with a hello world test.c file and these commands:

```
make test.exe
make test.exe
make test.exe CFLAGS="-g -Wall"
make test.exe CFLAGS="-g -Wall"
make test.exe
```

Answer (score 0):

My approach, so far, consists of generating a file, `cc-options-dump`, with the contents of the expansion of the `COMPILE.c` variable everytime `lib.o` is built.

The MD5 hash resulting of the expansion of the current `COMPILE.c` variable is compared against the one that was used for the previous build, i.e., the one whose contents are stored in the file `cc-options-dump`, if any (i.e., if the file does exist).

```
.PHONY: foo bar require-rebuild cc-options-dump

# include the xxx/config.mk files
# sort built-in function to make it independent of the order (i.e., "foo bar" or "bar foo")
$(foreach opt,$(sort $(MAKECMDGOALS)),$(eval include $(opt)/config.mk))

# obtain the MD5 hash of the previously used flags
ifneq (,$(wildcard cc-options-dump))
prev-cc-options-hash := $(shell md5sum cc-options-dump | cut -f1 -d' ')
endif

# obtain the MD5 hash of the current flags
curr-cc-options-hash := $(shell echo "$(COMPILE.c)" | md5sum | cut -f1 -d' ')

# Do these hashes differ?
ifneq ($(prev-cc-options-hash),$(curr-cc-options-hash))
# keep track of the fact that a rebuilt needs to be triggered
does-need-rebuild := require-rebuild
# just for displaying information
$(info Rebuild required)
else
$(info Rebuild not required)
endif

# make both targets foo and bar dependent on the file with the flags
# so that it has to be generated, since it is a phony target as well 
foo bar: cc-options-dump

# lib.o has now an additional prerequisite for determining whether it need to be rebuilt
lib.o: $(does-need-rebuild)

# save the used compiler flags for comparing them with the future flags
cc-options-dump: lib.o
    @echo '$(COMPILE.c)' >$@
```

The behaviour of this makefile when calling `make` for the targets `foo` and/or `bar` corresponds, as far as I can see, to the desired one:

```
$ make foo
Rebuild required
cc -DFOO   -c -o lib.o lib.c

$ make foo
Rebuild not required

$ make bar
Rebuild required
cc -DBAR   -c -o lib.o lib.c

$ make bar
Rebuild not required

$ make foo bar
Rebuild required
cc -DBAR -DFOO   -c -o lib.o lib.c

$ make bar foo
Rebuild not required
```

The use of the [`sort`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Text-Functions.html) built-in function is crucial for the last two cases above to work correctly.

It would be great if someone could come with a more elegant solution.